# Moving SAS dataset into SQL Server WITHOUT using SSIS packages

Tags: sql-server-2012, sas, vb.net-2010

I have a vb.net 2010 project that would remotely run a prepared SSIS package that exports a SAS 9.3 dataset into a SQL Server 2012 database. As far as I can tell, the process tested fine.

However, I was told not to use it (because SSIS packages are unreliable?), so are there alternatives to doing this?

I have looked up SAS ODBC to see if I can do this from the SAS end, but I am not sure of the DSN argument, the [example](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2703/using-sas-access-and-proc-sql-to-retrieve-sql-server-data/) I looked up is like this:

```
LIBNAME SQL ODBC DSN='sqlsrv_nt' schema=MSSQLTips;
```

Besides not being sure that the DSN is applicable for me, I  am not administrator on my workstation so I can't play with ODBC settings much - I'm not certain that's the way to go.

Comment: Forgive me but did you try this command and if so what error emerged?

Comment: I was not sure of the syntax but just found instructions to setting up ODBC connection to SQL server, trying now. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use a driver or DSN (customized shortcut data source connection object with all configurations/settings set). Once connected, append your data from local to remote source.

```
* WITH DSN;
libname mssqldata odbc datasrc="DSN Name" user="username" password="password";

* WITH DRIVER;
libname mssqldata odbc complete="driver={SQL Server}; Server=servername; user=username; pwd=password; database=databasename;";

** APPEND TO DATABASE TABLE;
proc datasets;
    append base = mssqldata.DBTable
    data = Work.SASdataset
    force;
quit;

** UN-ASSIGN ODBC LIBRARY;
libname mssqldata clear;
```

Be very careful with assigning library to database as it is a live connection and not copies. Hence, modifying/adding/deleting will reflect immediately to server.

Comment: Yeah. My goal is just to emulate what the SSIS package does, copy a sas dataset over (not overwrite). One thing about user name and password: Can I use a trusted connection to SQL server? I'm used to doing that when I connect directly to SQL in my VS projects so I never had to provide name ans password.

Comment: Great to hear! Glad it worked out and that I could help.

Comment: Even though I noticed it takes longer to run then the SSIS package... Well if they wants it, they gets it. But thank you for this quick help!

Comment: Hmmm I just noticed a typo in the library assignment but can't edit my old comment. So I'll just delete the old comment and post the statement I went with in the end (sorry I don't know how to linebreak in comments)--> libname mssqldata odbc complete="driver={SQL Server}; Server=servername; database=databasename; Trusted_Connection=Yes;";

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to be administrator. Set up a DSN connection under user profile. Then assign your libname and you can upload or update data in SQL server as permissions allow.

Your libname statement looks correct.

Comment: OK, tried as you have suggested via instructions here. http://support.sas.com/techsup/technote/ts765.pdf Will proceed with further testing. Thank you.